# System Verilog Initial process compilation error

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

A typical way of initializing a memory array is to assign the initial values in "Initial" process.

But the compiler complains that I cannot have two drivers on "mem" by a always_ff/always_comb/always_latch processes ...

```
   logic [15:0] mem [0:255];  

   initial
      begin 
        mem = '{default: 128};
      end

   // Synchronous Write to RAM
   always_ff @ (posedge sys_clkh)
   begin
         if(in_wr_enh) 
            mem[in_wr_adh] <= in_dth;
   end

   // Asynchronous Read from RAM
   assign out_dth = mem[in_rd_adh];
```

How can I fix this issue?
I don't want to use it in this fashion:

`logic [15:0] mem [0:255] = '{default: 128}`

Because the only way that the synthesis tool will understand this is to have it in initial process

Comment: Assigning to a signal from two processes is generally not synthesizable. Why don't you initialize it in the same `always_ff` block with a reset signal? How do you expect the synthesis tool to initialize it if not with reset?

Comment: There are examples of Xilinx documentation that shows how to initialize the RAM, and they recommending the "initial" block : http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2013_1/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf

Comment: I also opened up this thread in their forum: http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/General-Technical-Discussion/Xilinx-Block-Distributed-RAM-initialization-for-synthesis/m-p/566239#M22544

Comment: Ok, I can see on page 109 that they initialize the RAM in an initial block, but I think this is a special tool-specific case, and you really have to make sure the tool understands that it should instantiate a RAM block not flops. You may want to check the `RAM_STYLE_ on page 44.

Comment: Using `initial` to set default values is common for FPGA designs. It will not work for ASIC were a reset should be used. Do you still get the error if you use `always @ (posedge sys_clkh)`.

Comment: no. I don't. I used always instead. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Initializing a RAM like this is used only to make the simulation look nice. On real silicon (regardless of whether it's an FPGA or an ASIC) your RAM cells will have an undefined value when powering up. To model this, a logic simulator uses the `U` (in VHDL) or the `X` (in Verilog) values.

I'd advise against initializing any RAMs as this can hide issues where your device reads from cells that weren't written with an explicit value beforehand. If you read any undefined values, these will propagate through your design and (hopefully) hit an assertion or make your test fail in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

If the target is a Xilinx FPGA you can preload the RAM contents on powerup. I'd suggest using the Xilinx Block Memory Generator (under Customize IP in Vivado) which allows you to specify either an init file to load into memory or to fill memory locations.

One thing to be careful about if you use an approach of preloading a RAM--the behavior you get after a soft reset is different that the behavior after a power on reset (which reloads the FPGA bitfile) because the RAM doesn't get reinitialized--you'll still have whatever info was in the RAM prior to the reset. Your design needs to take this into account and simulate both conditions if your system supports soft resets.  (Actually the same condition applies for any signals given an initial condition, something only supported in FPGAs and not in ASICs. Xilinx tends to gloss over this issue when they encourage people to use initial conditions rather than reset logic).

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to change "always_ff" to "always".